# server doesn't recognise the end of file - java

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

So I have a Java Client server application. When I am trying to send a single file to the server (using SSLSockets) it works fine (because the connection is closed straight after the byte array of the file is sent). Although, as soon as I try to send a second file inputStream reader loop hangs (probably receives more bytes after the transfer? IDK). I ll write the block of code slightly modified so the structures are visible underneath.

> client

```
OutputStream = sslsocket.getOutputStream();

public void sendFile(Path pathOfFile){
    byte[] bytesToSend = Files.readAllBytes(pathOfFile);
    out.write(bytesToSend);
    out.flush();
}
```

> server

```
public void receiver(File file){
    InputStream in = sslsocket.getInputStream();

    byte[] fileBytes = new byte[sslsocket.getReceiveBufferSize()];
    int temp = 0;
    while ((temp = in.read(fileBytes)) > 0) { // stalls after a couple of reads
        file.write(fileBytes , 0, temp);
    }
}
```

so if I close the connection straight after the `sendFile` method everything works fine. But if I even run the client on debug and breakpoint straight after the `sendFile` method the server just freezes on the `read()` method of the `while` loop. What is going on??

Comment: This code does not compile. What does the real code look like? NB Your tile was both more specific and more accurate before the edit: rolled it back.

Comment: I did copy it from another machine that doesn't have internet access. The blocks of code are the same as my actual.

Comment: No they're not. There is no such method as `getReceivedBufferSize()`. It's a typo.

Comment: that's a typo. sorry one "d" too much

Answer (score 0):

> doesn't recognize the end of file

There is no end of file to recognize unless you close the connection.

You're reading the socket until end of stream, which only happens when the peer closes the connection. If you don't close the connection, the receiver will block.

Comment: so for every file that needs to be transferred I need another connection? Can't be possible.

Comment: No, you need different code that doesn't rely on end of stream to delimit each file.